# OKTA Authentication with ASP.Net Core throws unhandled exception when user not assigned to client application

Tags: asp.net-core, okta

I've integrated OKTA to my ASP.Net Core application from the following tutorial:
https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/okta-sign-in-page/dotnet/aspnetcore

It works fine if a user is assigned to my OKTA application, but if not I get an unhandled exception in the authorization callback:

> OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error:
>   'access_denied', error_description: 'User is not assigned to the
>   client application.', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.

I would like to catch this exception and handle it gracefully.

With OpenId, you could create an OnRemoteFailure event that to deal with this, but I can't figure out how to do it with the Okta.AspNetCore library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default schema of Okta.AspNetCore is `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;

namespace Okta.AspNetCore
{
    public static class OktaDefaults
    {
        public const string MvcAuthenticationScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        public const string ApiAuthenticationScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        public const string CallbackPath = "/authorization-code/callback";

        public const string SignOutCallbackPath = "/signout/callback";

        public static readonly string[] Scope = new string[] { "openid", "profile" };
    }
}
```

So you can  configure the `OpenIdConnectOptions` by using the scheme names from above, including access to `OpenIdConnectEvents`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OktaDefaults.MvcAuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions
{
    // Replace these values with your Okta configuration
    OktaDomain = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:OktaDomain"),
    ClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:ClientId"),
    ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:ClientSecret"),
});
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async ctxt =>
        {
            // Invoked before redirecting to the identity provider to authenticate. This can be used to set ProtocolMessage.State
            // that will be persisted through the authentication process. The ProtocolMessage can also be used to add or customize
            // parameters sent to the identity provider.
            await Task.Yield();
        },
        OnMessageReceived = async ctxt =>
        {
            // Invoked when a protocol message is first received.
            await Task.Yield();
        },
        OnTicketReceived = async ctxt =>
        {
            // Invoked after the remote ticket has been received.
            // Can be used to modify the Principal before it is passed to the Cookie scheme for sign-in.
            // This example removes all 'groups' claims from the Principal (assuming the AAD app has been configured
            // with "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"). Group memberships can be checked here and turned into
            // roles, to be persisted in the cookie.

            await Task.Yield();
        },
        OnRemoteFailure = context =>
        {

            ..........
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("AccessDenied?error=" + context.Failure.Message);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        },
    };
});
```